# Why won't my health go down after cheat mod disabled?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, cheats

So my question is about that I downloaded the cheat room mod because I got stuck in some cave because the bloodskal blade would not shoot its beam and I went to the room drank a health potion and now I un-download it, because its not fun with cheats, but now my health won't take damage, what do I do? I un-downloaded it and I'm on XboxOne and I do not want to go back to an old save. I got rid of other cheat items but my health won't go down when attacked.

Comment: Start over without cheats.

Comment: All what you can do is reload a previous save. IF that don't work, to be honest, it is out of our help since we don't really deal with modding much, less when we don't know which mod you are using. Edit your question to tell us the name of the mod.

Comment: One other thing: make sure if the Bloodskal blade works. You have to power attack to shoot the red beams.

Answer (score 4):

You need to load from a save prior to when you had the cheat installed.

Console mods for Skyrim and Fallout 4 are often somewhat hacky, as they lack the options and script extension options that exist for PC.  Many mod authors who do console mods also are relatively new modders compared to those who place content on the Nexus, as many of the more seasoned modders refuse to participate in Bethesda's console mods.

What has probably happened is that the "mod" simply set your maximum health to a ridiculous amount, set your native damage resistance so high that you can't be effectively injured, or bypassed the lack of console commands by effectively setting "TGM" (godmode) to true and had no method of turning it off.

In any of those scenarios, all saves made after the mod was active will be permanently affected by the mod. This really only leaves you with one choice.